# How to solve the error in autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting error in autocomplete.

Js:

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", 
  "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", 
   "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", 
  "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
  })
 .directive('autoComplete', function ($timeout) {
  return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    iElement.autocomplete({
        source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
        select: function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                iElement.trigger('input');
            }, 0);
        }
    });
};
});
```

Html:

```
 <div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

I am getting the error shown in below screenshot:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try $(iElement).autocomplete(...)

Comment: Try to update your return statement as below
return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: names,
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    }

Comment: iElement doesn't have autocomplete function. Maybe you can wrap it with $(jquery)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  working example which may helps you

```
    <div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input complete ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
    </div>

    angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('complete', function($timeout) {
    var names = ["john", "James", "Raj"];

    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: names,
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```